# Getting products with Craft 3 and Craft Commerce 2

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, craft3

I've never had success using Craft 3 with Commerce 2 beta. I always get an error that ".find()" is not recognized, and ".all()" doesn't work either.

My latest attempt has given me this error:

> Twig Runtime Error – Twig_Error_Runtime
>   Calling unknown method: craft\commerce\services\Products::type()

The line in question is this one:

```
{% set silentItems = craft.commerce.products.type('silentAuctionItems').find() %}
```

If I delete

```
.type('silentAuctionItems').find()
```

the error doesn't come up, but I don't get any products displaying.

I've searched through the Commerce documentation, and I can't find anything about this problem.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: My mistake: I actually have Commerce 2 beta running on this installation. I installed Commerce through the Craft 3 plugin store. And it's still giving me the template errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
craft.product.type(x).all()
```

Will do it, without `commerce`

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem. It should be

```
{% set silentItems = craft.products.type('silentAuctionItems').all() %}
```

You don't put .commerce between craft and .products.

Thanks!

Comment: Documentation link for posterity: https://github.com/craftcms/commerce-docs/blob/v2/en/changes-in-commerce-2.md#product-queries